# How to take the last row according to index when multiple tickers share the index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi I have spent so many hours trying to solve this unsuccessfully.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\MichaelBerman\Dropbox\Code\Python\Mike-Code\data.csv", index_col=0)
# Converting the index as date
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df)
```

What the data looks like:

[image]

The way the data is stored is each ticker runs from a certain date until yesterday 2023-04-02.
I am trying to pull out the data for each ticker on 2023-04-02

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

I have tried grouping and using last but it takes the data for the last ticker and applies it to all the tickers,

What I tried:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.loc`:

```
# Using string
>>> df.loc['2023-04-02']

# Using the most recent date
>>> df.loc[df.index.max()]

# Using yesterday
>>> df.loc[pd.Timestamp.today().date() - pd.DateOffset(days=1)]
```

**Tips**: `read_csv` can convert the index as datetime using `parse_dates` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"data.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the data for each ticker separately, you can loop over the unique tickers use the `loc` method to extract the data:

```
tickers = df['Ticker'].unique()

for ticker in tickers:
    ticker_data = df.loc[(df['Ticker'] == ticker) & (df.index == '2023-04-02')]
    # Do something with the ticker_data
```

Comment: just use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html before loc operation

Comment: thanks all, this all worked. It turned out I somehow left a fixed ticker symbol in my data prep that kept over-writing everything I feel so stupid.
Probably landed up spending 10hrs on this but the truth is strong learning came from it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an easier alternative solution.

Pivot table

```
p_table = pd.pivot_table(df_f, index= df_f.loc[pd.Timestamp(date.today() - timedelta(1)), ['ticker'] ]) 
print(p_table)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abt9z.png)